# Split a matrix into a list while preserving rownames

Tags: r, matrix, split

I have a matrix that has rownames:

```
mat1.data <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
mat1 <- matrix(mat1.data,nrow=3,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
rownames(mat1) <- c("a", "b", "c")
colnames(mat1) <- c("t1", "t2")
```

Expected outcome

```
$t1
a b c     #I need to preserve rownames
1 3 5

$t2
a b c
2 4 6
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `asplit` with `MARGIN = 2` to split column-wise:

```r
asplit(mat1, 2)
```

output

```r
$t1
a b c 
1 3 5 

$t2
a b c 
2 4 6
```